# How to show button in gridview if a column empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application i have only one editable column and if that editable column is empty i need to show add link button but it displays edit link button.How can i display add as the link button if that particular editable column in gridview is empty

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <itemtemplate>
         <asp:Button Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty() %>' runat="server" Text="Edit" ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
         <asp:Button Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty() %>' runat="server" Text="Add" ID="Add" CommandName="Edit" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

i tried this but it is working but unable to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `TemplateField` to the GridView with 2 buttons that have a Visibility based on a column value.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <itemtemplate>
         <asp:Button Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("editableField").ToString()) %>' runat="server" Text="Edit" ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
         <asp:Button Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("editableField").ToString()) %>' runat="server" Text="Add" ID="Add" CommandName="Edit" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That's a whole different question. You are talking about `EdititemTemplates` with `OnRowCancelingEdit, OnRowEditing, OnRowUpdating` events etc. Thats too broad a question. In this [basic tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control) is all the info you need to get started. If you are still stuck after that ask a more specific question.